# What is the difference between http:// and // in HTML

Tags: html, x-editable

I'm using this x-editable library, and it works really well. But I still have one problem.

In this [x-editable page](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/),in the use CDN section, you can see something like this

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

I'm tested examples and it works. And it seems that the above 2 lines instruct browser to fetch css and js files from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com. My question is: Is there any difference between **http://** and **//** here.

Comment: Well, I think that the // depends on the current http method (it means that if you have https, it will connect using https) and http://, I think you know, it's like relative and absolute path

Answer (score 5):

It'll pick the `http://` or `https://` based on the protocol that is being used.

If the current page is `https` it will access the href using `https`.

If `http` then the link is accessed over plain `http`.